# can I use ddmlib in an android application?

Tags: android, ddms

can I use ddmlib in an android application? as we all know, ddmlib can be used in PC Host,but can I use ddmlib in an android app run in android host?

Comment: 12-09 00:47:16.530: I/System.out(23666): 12:47:16 E/DeviceMonitor: adb refused request: closed
12-09 00:47:16.530: I/System.out(23666): 12:47:16 E/DeviceMonitor: Sending Tracking request failed!
12-09 00:47:16.530: I/System.out(23666): 12:47:16 E/DeviceMonitor: Adb connection Error:EOF